# How to put button on the bottom of PageViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller

[image: I]

As shown on the image, I have ContentViewController, PageViewController and WelcomeController. And you can see, that I have buttons on my WelcomeController, in the bottom.

With the code: http://pastebin.com/Kf70RQWM

I put PageView with the ContentView into my WelcomeController, but it covers whole my screen. I did try using this:

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 50)
```

to have 50px space for my buttons, but in that case I get the next:

[image]

black background instead of my buttons.

Question: how can I put my buttons to those black space?

Comment: Use a container view in your welcome controller to embed your page controller

Comment: can i see your code sir?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin http://pastebin.com/Kf70RQWM

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: can you push your sample project to github so I can take a look at it.

Comment: @Paulw11 I did try it, but container appears below this black area, not inside

Comment: Then you haven't set your constraints properly.

Comment: @Paulw11 look at this please: git@bitbucket.org:alizade/messenger.git

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin please: git@bitbucket.org:alizade/messenger.git

Comment: can you push it on github?

Comment: That isn't a valid URL.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin git@github.com:orkhanalizade/messenger.git

Comment: @Paulw11 from github: git@github.com:orkhanalizade/messenger.git

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to setup autolayout. Please check the pull request here, https://github.com/orkhanalizade/messenger/pull/1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can learn it here, my friend. http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1. Please upvote and mark as accepted.